# meta tag description

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML: How to get my subpages listed on a google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739898/html-how-to-get-my-subpages-listed-on-a-google-search)

I was wondering how to make( write) meta tag description like facebook has. I mean if you search facebook on google you see the way it presented. It shows a bunch of links and their descriptions!

Any idea or help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a description to show on Google within your `<head>` tags:

`<meta name="description" content="Description here" />`

As far as placing links underneath the main page, Google automates the process, although there are some changes you can make. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334